# PHP как узнать с какого сайта произошел редирект на текущую страницу?

Tags: php

PHP как узнать с какого сайта произошел редирект на текущую страницу?

Answer (score 3):

Можно из глобальной переменной `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, но referer не является обязательным заголовком, поэтому не всегда возможно по нему определить, к тому-же не обязательно там будет правда.